# Combine if-query with allocation

Tags: php, optimization, web

Is it possible to combine the allocation into the if-query and should that be done?

```
$textxPos = $xPos + $fieldData["coordinates"]["x"] / $divisor;
if ($textxPos < 0) {
  ..
}
```

like so:

```
if ($link['value'] = trim($link['value'])) {
  ..
}
```

Comment: is it possible? yes. should it be done? highly subjective. in most cases, though, the answer is no, because it makes the code harder to understand and less intuitive. there are few examples where it is commonplace (`while($row = fetch_something())`), but mostly you should refrain from it IMHO.

Comment: "should that be done?" No.
@FranzGleichmann Nice example.. but thats in a while loop. I don't know if its even possible to do something like that in a if condition..?

Comment: @RamaLingam For you same as for WEBiuiu... just read his question again. Your answer didn't help him, its intentionally that there's only one equal.

Comment: @Twinfriends yeah, but internally, a while is nothing but an if with a goto. and the basic principle of the question remains the same: *variable asignment inside control structures, yay or nay?* i personally tend to nay, and to closing this question as primarily opinion-based

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Okay you're right. So means if($row = _fetch_*()) would be true if there is data to fetch?

Comment: @Julli Schaf Try my solution. I hope it will help you!

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
if(($textxPos = $xPos + $fieldData["coordinates"]["x"] / $divisor) && $textxPos<0 )
{
    echo "true";
}
else
{   
    echo "false";
}
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
$var1 = "112";
$var2 = "112";
$divisor = "10";

if(($textxPos = $var1 + $var2 / $divisor) && $textxPos<0 )
{
    echo "true";
}
else
{   
    echo "false"; //$textxPos=123.2
}
?>
```

First assign the value to `$textxPos` next check the condition by Using `&&` operator.

Comment: @Julli Schaf: Within `if` condition we can able to assign or act any operation.